# Removing portion from scraped array

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I am scraping a website and I am trying to remove a portion of the code which I don't want to be included in the array.

so the code I have currently

```
$content['article'] = $html2->find('.hentry-content',0);
$content['article'] = $content['article']->plaintext;
```

This returns everything within the `.hentry-content` class on the website I am gathering content from.

Now the content that gets returned looks like this.

```
array (
[article] => This is some example filler content please no actual meaning behind random bridge for bridge random you dog tomorrow http://example.com/our-random-mp3.com
)
```

Now at the end of this output it usually includes a random MP3 is there anyway that I can pull just the content portion of the array without the mp3 being included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if link is inside of `<a>` tag this should work

```
foreach($content['article']->find('a') as $item) {
    $item->outertext = '';
}

echo $content['article']->plaintext;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the returned text only contains one link to the random mp3-file you could filter it out with:

```
$url_pattern = '/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/';
$content['article'] = preg_replace($url_pattern, '', $content['article']->plaintext);
```

This will remove all urls from the text. I took the url-pattern from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149.

Comment: This does not work, it returns url that looks like this. http://ourwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/some-name.mp3

Comment: Try removing the ^ in the url pattern. It checks if the string begins with this pattern.